# Pass parameter from one spring boot microservice to another without displaying on URL

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, java-8, microservices

We have multiple spring-boot-microservices running and to communicate wihin them we are using something like

ModelAndView("redirect:/"+url)

Now with this redirection we are passing modelMap for parameters but the issue is that modelMap content is visible on URL, what is the best way to pass these values without being displayed on URL?

I have tried using redirectAttribute with flashAttribute but facing issues, Is there any other way? 
And what's the best suggested practice for above scenario?

Comment: how about dropping cookies in browser?

Comment: This is a web application which will be used by clients, So we cannot ask every client to drop cookies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use a proxying approach wherein the microservice that sends back the redirect command could fetch the data and return it in behalf of the invoked API. Typically, you would want to utilise [Apache HTTP Client](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi) to invoke a remote API.

This will eliminate the need to show the parameters on the client-side.

Regards,
Allan

Comment: WIll give it a try, But a bit confuse on the redirect part.